# Creating a new column with time groups

Tags: r

I have a dataset named "BEDATA2" which has a column that provides an hour in which a crime happened, for example 22. The column name is "occurence_hour".

I am attempting to create a new column within my dataset which would bucket the timestamps into a few categories based on what is in the "occurrence_hour" column. There would be four 6-hour time windows beginning at midnight. The four-time intervals are 00-06 (midnight to 6am), 06-12 (6 AM to noon), 12-18 (noon to 6 PM), and 18-00 (6 PM to midnight).

The smallest "occurrence_hour" is 0 and the highest is 23.

My assumption would maybe that I'd probably use the cut function to match a timestamp under "occurrence_hour" to a time group under the "timegroup" column but never got that far as I'm having trouble creating a new column with the necessary time groups.

Dataset:

```
structure(list(event_unique_id = c("GO-20141260291", "GO-20141260701", 
    "GO-20141260233", "GO-20141260831", "GO-20141260521"), occurrence_date = structure(c(1388534400, 
    1388534400, 1388534400, 1388534400, 1388534400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), occurrence_yrmn = c("2014-January", "2014-January", 
    "2014-January", "2014-January", "2014-January"), reported_date = structure(c(1388534400, 
    1388534400, 1388534400, 1388534400, 1388534400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), reportedy_rmn = c("2014-January", "2014-January", 
    "2014-January", "2014-January", "2014-January"), location_type = c("Other Commercial / Corporate Places (For Profit, Warehouse, Corp. Bldg", 
    "Commercial Dwelling Unit (Hotel, Motel, B & B, Short Term Rental)", 
    "Other Commercial / Corporate Places (For Profit, Warehouse, Corp. Bldg", 
    "Single Home, House (Attach Garage, Cottage, Mobile)", "Bar / Restaurant"
    ), premises_type = c("Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", 
    "House", "Commercial"), reported_dayofweek = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday"), reported_hour = c(1, 
    3, 2, 3, 2), occurrence_dayofweek = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday"), occurrence_hour = c(1, 
    3, 1, 3, 2), MCI = c("Break and Enter", "Break and Enter", "Break and Enter", 
    "Break and Enter", "Break and Enter"), Hood_ID = c("71", "70", 
    "126", "136", "81"), Neighbourhood = c("Cabbagetown-South St.James Town", 
    "South Riverdale", "Dorset Park", "West Hill", "Trinity-Bellwoods"
    ), Object_Id = c(103, 104, 105, 106, 109)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Seems like 6, 12, 18 fall into two different categories.  Would probably need a slightly different definition.

Comment: Not sure I understand, my apologies. The idea is that if for example the "occurrence_hour" = 6 , then it would fall into the time_group "6-12". If the "occurrence_hour" is 14 then it would fall into the time_group "12-18" .

The smallest "occurence_hour" is 0 and the highest is 23. @RuiBarradas

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. All clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the breaks vector to include both end points of the hours range and `cut` will create a factor variable. The labels are set in the same call.

```r
labs <- c("00-06", "06-12", "12-18", "18-00")
brks <- c(0, 6, 12, 18, 24)

cut(BEDATA2$occurrence_hour, breaks = brks, labels = labs, include.lowest = TRUE)
#> [1] 00-06 00-06 00-06 00-06 00-06
#> Levels: 00-06 06-12 12-18 18-00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Now just assign this value to a new column. With `include.lowest` set to TRUE `cut` outputs left-closed intervals.

```r
BEDATA2$timegroup <- cut(BEDATA2$occurrence_hour, breaks = brks, labels = labs, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

### Note

I find the last interval's label `"18-24"` clearer than `"18-00"`. This repeats one of the first label's end points, `"00"`.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try this. I did have a question, I see the function BEDATA@$timegroup however there is a function creating the timegroup column, it doesn't exist yet. Unless I may be missing something. @RuiBarradas

Comment: @Amantryingtolearn `BEDATA@$timegroup` is not a function, it's the new column created by function `cut`.